# User for outgoing mails in O365

Tags: office365

I want to have a user which is only able to login to my O365 Exchange via an external program and send mails to external users.

What is the preferred way of achieving this? Do I really have to license a complete new user?

Edit: Current settings for a test user in portal are:

[image: Test user settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, this is the license I have to use:

[image: Additional O365 license]

I testet it and it works because when I assign this license to the functional account it is able to send mails.

My problem is solved but I'm not sure if Microsoft is serious about this. I can't believe that I really have to spent 3 Euros to get this feature working.